# Generics wtih anonymous Delegates expressed a lambdas... Ithink

Tags: c#, generics, lambda, anonymous-function

So I'm trying to do something just slightly beyond the edge of my
understanding... in three different ways. Let me explain what I'm
trying to do then I'll get to the particulars of my lack of
understanding.

I have several Dictionaries, that contain objects I need to generate
reports. they are all

```
ConcurrentDictionary< Int64, List< EarningsReportCV>>
```

where earnings CV is a custom object that only contains
properties(custom View model).

I have three of these dictionaries...and the code to init them is
almost identical, they each just contain a different class CV.

Here is one example:

```
private void BuildDictForAllEarn( List<EarningsReportCV> list, ConcurrentDictionary<Int64, List<EarningsReportCV>> theDict )
{
    foreach ( EarningsReportCV cv in list )
    {
        if ( theDict.ContainsKey( Convert.ToInt64( cv.Ssn ) ) )
        {
            //append in list already in Dict - EWB
            theDict[ Convert.ToInt64( cv.Ssn ) ].Add( cv );
        }
        else
        {
            //insert inital list into the Dict - EWB
            List<EarningsReportCV> cvList = new List<EarningsReportCV>();
            cvList.Add( cv );
            theDict.AddOrUpdate( Convert.ToInt64( cv.Ssn ), cvList, ( foundkey, oldvalue  => cvList );
        }
    }
}
```

All three Dictionaries are keyed off a string `<T>.Ssn`

Instead of having copy and paste code with just the types of the CV
changing, I want to make a generic method. To do this I need to pass
in a anonymous delegate that allows me to generically take the passed
in type T and get it's .Ssn property to use as the key.

I googled and thought and read and got this far...

Generic:

```
 private void BuildDict<T>( List<T> list, ConcurrentDictionary<Int64, List<T>> theDict, Func<T, string> getIndexFunc )

 {
     foreach ( T cv in list )
     {
         if ( theDict.ContainsKey( Convert.ToInt64( getIndexFunc( cv ) ) ) )
         {
             //append in list already in Dict - EWB
             theDict[ Convert.ToInt64( getIndexFunc( cv ) ) ].Add( cv );
         }
         else
         {
             //insert inital list into the Dict - EWB
             List<EarningsReportCV> cvList = new List<EarningsReportCV>();
             cvList.Add( cv );
             theDict.AddOrUpdate( Convert.ToInt64( getIndexFunc( cv ) ), cvList, ( foundkey, oldvalue ) => cvList );
         }
     }
 }
```

which I call thusly

```
private void BuildDictForAllEarnLAMBDA( List<EarningsReportCV> list, ConcurrentDictionary<Int64, List<EarningsReportCV>> theDict )
{
    BuildDict<EarningsReportCV>( list, theDict, ( T ) => { return T.Ssn; } );// fix this lambda as paramether stuff...- EWB
}
```

I *think* I get everything there except the 3r d parameter, which I
want to pass in as a lambda to look up the .Ssn property of the
generic type `<T>`.

When I compile it , I get these errors..

> Error 43  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'T' to
>   'EFRGPayroll3G.CV.EarningsReportCV'   C:\Users\Brown.Ericw\Documents\Visual
>   Studio
>   2013\Projects\WindowsService1\WindowsService1\BLL\RazorReportRenderBLL.cs 406 33  WindowsService1
>   Error 45  Argument 2: cannot convert from
>   `'System.Collections.Generic.List<EFRGPayroll3G.CV.EarningsReportCV>'`
>   to
>   `'System.Func<long,System.Collections.Generic.List<T>>'`  C:\Users\Brown.Ericw\Documents\Visual
>   Studio
>   2013\Projects\WindowsService1\WindowsService1\BLL\RazorReportRenderBLL.cs 407 81  WindowsService1
>   Error 46  Argument 3: cannot convert from 'lambda expression' to
>   `'System.Func<long,System.Collections.Generic.List<T>,System.Collections.Generic.List<T>>'`   C:\Users\Brown.Ericw\Documents\Visual
>   Studio
>   2013\Projects\WindowsService1\WindowsService1\BLL\RazorReportRenderBLL.cs 407 89  WindowsService1
>   Error 44  The best overloaded method match for
>   `'System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary<long,System.Collections.Generic.List<T>>.AddOrUpdate(long, System.Func<long,System.Collections.Generic.List<T>> System.Func<long,System.Collections.Generic.List<T>, System.Collections.Generic.List<T>>)'`
>   has some invalid arguments    C:\Users\Brown.Ericw\Documents\Visual
>   Studio
>   2013\Projects\WindowsService1\WindowsService1\BLL\RazorReportRenderBLL.cs 407 21  WindowsService1
>   Error 42  The best overloaded method match for
>   `'System.Collections.Generic.List<EFRGPayroll3G.CV.EarningsReportCV>.Add(EFRGPayroll3G.CV.EarningsReportCV)'`
>   has some invalid arguments    C:\Users\Brown.Ericw\Documents\Visual
>   Studio
>   2013\Projects\WindowsService1\WindowsService1\BLL\RazorReportRenderBLL.cs 406 21  WindowsService1

and at that point I no longer understand what's going on...my brain is just full... what do I do to take this to a functional piece of code. I'm looking for both what to do, and what it is I need to grok to wrap my head around this and best of all good articles to explain it to me... Any even small glimmerings of understanding are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why have you written nearly your whole question as quoted text?

Comment: I dont' know, the editor did that at some point when I was trying to quote just the errors, I'm going back and fixing it manually because the "unquote" button didn't work... it just left it there.. I just wanted to save it before going back. Looks like you beat me to it. Thanks Jon!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line `List<EarningsReportCV> cvList = new List<EarningsReportCV>();` Should be using `T`, not `EarningsReportCV`.

You made your function generic but simply forgot to change those two instances of the old concrete class to the generic type.  The method compiles after that change.

Having said that, there are several issues that you should probably change in your function.

First and foremost, it appears to attempt to be safe to be called from multiple threads, but it's not.  A key could be added or removed in another thread after you check to see if it exists, resulting in items being dropped on the floor.

The premise of your program is to add an item if it's not there, and update it if it is.  That *exactly* what `AddOrUpdate` is designed to do, atomically.  You should simply be calling that once, rather than what you're doing.  It even makes the code simpler.

```
private void BuildDict<T>(List<T> list,
    ConcurrentDictionary<long, List<T>> theDict,
    Func<T, string> getIndexFunc)
{
    foreach (T cv in list)
    {
        theDict.AddOrUpdate(Convert.ToInt64(getIndexFunc(cv)),
            key => new List<T>() { cv },
            (foundkey, oldvalue) =>
            {
                oldvalue.Add(cv);
                return oldvalue;
            });
    }
}
```

There are some other changes that you can make to improve the code as well.  Since you only ever iterate `list` and never do anything else, you can make that parameter an `IEnumerable`, allowing it to be any type of sequence beyond just lists.

If you're program is designed to be accessing and manipulating `theDict` from multiple threads, it's very likely that the inner lists shouldn't be lists, but should be a collection designed to be accessed from multiple threads, such as a `ConcurrentBag`.

Since the delegate you're accepting really wants a `long`, not a `string`, that's really what it should accept, rather than accepting a `string` and trying to convert it.

This gives us:

```
private void BuildDict<T>(IEnumerable<T> sequence,
    ConcurrentDictionary<long, ConcurrentBag<T>> theDict,
    Func<T, long> keySelector)
{
    foreach (T cv in sequence)
    {
        theDict.AddOrUpdate(keySelector(cv),
            key => new ConcurrentBag<T>() { cv },
            (foundkey, oldvalue) =>
            {
                oldvalue.Add(cv);
                return oldvalue;
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: Dude you rock, I was starting right at that and just didn't see it. I greatly appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Since all three use `.Ssn` you don't need a access `Func<>`.  You need to tell the method they all have an Ssn:

```
  interface IHasSsn
  {
       string Ssn;
  }

private void BuildDict<T>( List<T> list, 
                           ConcurrentDictionary<Int64, List<T>> theDict)
   where T : IHasSsn
{
    foreach ( T cv in list )
    {
        long ssn = Convert.ToInt64( cv.Ssn );
        if ( theDict.ContainsKey(ssn) )
        {
            theDict[ssn].Add( cv );
        }
        else
        {
            var cvList = new List<T>();
            cvList.Add( cv );
            theDict.AddOrUpdate(ssn, cvList, ( foundkey, oldvalue  => cvList );
        }
    }
}
```

And make sure each ReportCV implements `IHasSsn`

Comment: Nice! that's a good approach too.. I was thinking base class, but Interface is much cleaner! thanks!